# connect to mysql database using visual studio 2010 remotely

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to connect to MySql db using VS2010. I added my ip address in cpanel allow hosts. I also grabbed the IP address for the server where the database is hosted which is just my website.

So I go to server explorer, right click database connections and clicked on add a connection

I select .NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL for Data Source
for Sever Name I typed the IP address for my website where the Database is
Typed in the user name and password who has all the privileges,  and entered the Database Name too.

When I hit test connection I always getting "Unable to connect to any of the specified hosts"

any advice is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is your hosting provider blocking the connection?

Comment: nope because I connect using Dreamweaver cs6

Comment: If you could connect to your database over the web using IP address, I guess you don't have a secure database.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to connect to a MySql database from VS2010 see the link bellow:

http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/09/09/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-visual-studio-vs2010-problems-with-net-connectors/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding % as your access host under Manage Remote MySQL Access of your Cpanel?

Try this
http://zambalestechrealm.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/vb-net-remote-access-to-mysql-database-of-my-website-2/

It says
Goto Your site Cpanel, and look for MySQL remote access, in my case i put % in the list of user to access remotely to my database. ‘%’ percent means to allow all connection to connect to my MySQL database.